# using express.json() after raw-body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

In my express app, I want to check the body length and limit it regardless of content-type. After this, I want to parse the body if content type is json. How can I achieve this? At the moment my code is like the following but server stops at express.json() middle-ware:

```js
const express = require('express')
const contentType = require('content-type')
const getRawBody = require('raw-body')

const app = express()

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const cType = req.headers['content-type'] || ''
    getRawBody(req, {
        length: req.headers['content-length'],
        limit: '1mb',
        encoding: contentType.parse(cType).parameters.charset
    }, function(err, string) {
        if(err) {
            next(err)
        }
        next()
    })
})

app.use(express.json())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement things that way.  `express.json()` expects to read the body contents from the incoming stream.  But, `raw-body` has already read the body contents from the stream so when `express.json()` tries to read it, it gets stuck waiting for there to be something to read.

Since `express.json()` does two things, read the body from the stream and then parse it into JSON, it should be easy to replace those two things with your own version.  The first is already done (reading the body)  so all you have to do is to call `JSON.parse()` on the raw body contents that you already read if (and only if), the content-type is `"application/json"`.  Remove the call to `express.json()`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const cType = req.headers['content-type'] || ''
    getRawBody(req, {
        length: req.headers['content-length'],
        limit: '1mb',
        encoding: contentType.parse(cType).parameters.charset
    }, function(err, string) {
        if(err) {
            next(err)
        } else {
            if (req.get('Content-Type').toLowerCase() === "application/json") {
                try {
                    // try parsing the body as JSON
                    req.body = JSON.parse(req.body);
                    next();
                } catch(e) {
                   console.log(e);
                   next(e);
                }
            } else {
                 // not JSON, will leave the raw body in req.body
                 next();
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Note, if your app is expecting any other content-types (like form data), you will also have to manually parse them since the standard express middleware for those other types will have the same issue.